# Own Title on hover - load other field

Tags: javascript, list-view

I have custom list named `LIST1` with fields `ID,Title,ShortComment,LongComment`.  I'am using view webpart , where only fields `ID,Title,ShortComment` are visible. Is there some way to show field `LongComment` on hover or other event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS or CSR or Calculated Columns; I answered this in detail 2 weeks ago:

[How to Truncate a multiline column in a SharePoint List 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151473/how-to-truncate-a-multiline-column-in-a-sharepoint-list-2013/151496#151496)

[image]

Comment: thank's a lot. I will study it soon...

Comment: Nice, I hope your CSS solution will be suitable for users.